# How to install type-graphql?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, npm, graphql

I want to import this in my TypeScript project:

```
import { ID } from "type-graphql";
```

but I am unable to install type-graphql. I tried this but it gave me a 404 error saying that this is not found in the nam registry

```
npm install @types/type-graphql
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

package with prefix `@types/` is only type definition for typescript

type-graphql is built on typescript, 
so you dont need install `@types/type-graphql` just install `type-graphql`

please follow the documentation https://typegraphql.com/docs/installation.html#packages-installation

Answer (score 0):

Basically you can search the [www.npmjs.com](https://www.npmjs.com/package/type-graphql)

If there is no such option, then there is no so-named package been published. And that's the reason for `404`

---

And since from their description, they have Typescript supported inside.

You may not need an extract `@Types/..` for this.

> Create GraphQL schema and resolvers with TypeScript, using classes and decorators!

---

[image]